# How to mock Angular 4.3 httpClient an error response in testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I have a below `interceptor auth-interceptor.service.ts`

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Cookie} from './cookie.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {ToasterService} from '../toaster/toaster.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
        let errorMsg;
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            errorMsg = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            errorMsg = `Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`;
        }
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
            this.injector.get(UserService).purgeAuth();
            this.injector.get(ToasterService).showError(`Unauthorized`, errorMsg);
            this.injector.get(Router).navigateByUrl(`/login`);
        }
        console.error(errorMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(Cookie.tokenKey, Cookie.getToken())});
        // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
        return next.handle(authReq).catch(err => this.handleError(err));
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to mock the `http.get` to throw the error, so that method `handleError` consoles the error message.

Below is my approach to the test case `auth-interceptor.service.specs.ts`

```
import {async, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {AuthInterceptor} from './auth-interceptor.service';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

describe(`AuthInterceptor`, () => {
    const somePath = `/somePath`;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [AuthInterceptor, ApiService]
        });
    });

    it(`should be created`, inject([AuthInterceptor], (service: AuthInterceptor) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));


    it(`should log an error to the console on error on get()`, async(inject([ApiService, HttpTestingController],
        (apiService: ApiService, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
            spyOn(console, 'error');
            apiService.get(somePath).subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(`in success:`, res);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(`in error:`, error);
            });

            const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${environment.apiUri}${somePath}`);
            req.flush({
                type: 'ERROR',
                status: 404,
                body: JSON.stringify({color: `blue`})
            });
            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }))
    );
});
```

When flushing the response, I am not sure how to flush a error response, so that the method `handleError` will be called in my interceptor and that eventually calls `console.error`. Documentation doesn't have any example to my situation. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your `req` object is an instance of `TestRequest` class. It also has `error()` method. Did you try something like `req.error(new ErrorEvent('fail'), {status: 404});`?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `expectOne` method in `HttpTestingController` class returns a `TestRequest` object. This TestRequest class has a `flush` method which can be used to deliver

> both successful and unsuccessful responses.

We can resolve the request by returning a body along with some additional response headers (if any). Relevant info can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest).

Now, coming back to the point how you can do this. You can customize the below code snippet as per your use case.

```
http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
let response: any;
let errResponse: any;
const mockErrorResponse = { status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request' };
const data = 'Invalid request parameters';
apiService.get(somePath).subscribe(res => response = res, err => errResponse = err);
http.expectOne('url/being/monitored').flush(data, mockErrorResponse);
expect(errResponse).toBe(data);
```

**NOTE**: At the time of writing this comment, `statusText` is required in `mockErrorResponse`. Related info can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5c62e300e1277971e9da9df3469bca7465da712b).

**P.S.**: The `error` method of `TestRequest` class can be used to simulate network error in our test case, as it expects an instance of Error. The following code snippet shows that.

```
http.expectOne(someUrl).error(new ErrorEvent('network error'));
```

Comment: If checking an error, should you not instead do `http.expectOne(someUrl).error(null, mockErrorResponse)`? Creating an `ErrorEvent` doesn't allow you to include a status code, so to me it seems less desirable than my proposed solution.

Comment: I am struggling with this.  If I have one jasmine unit test doing this it works.  If I have more than one, it is actually throwing the error I am trying to mock and killing the test cycle.

Comment: @Jimbo I had the same issue. My problem was that I was not adding the error callback. 

`apiService.get(somePath).subscribe(res => response = res, err => errResponse = err);` 

The second callback is really important and it could even be an empty function like `(err) => {}`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I like to add, that inside expectOne, you do not need an url, but you can just write ```() => true```. Also inside of the subscribe you do not need the first response part, just the ```errResponse``` part is sufficient for this test.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.` error on `.flush('not found',{status: 404, statusText: 'not found'})`