# Angular - Writing unit test case for error handling method

Tags: angular, jasmine

below are 2 methods in my service file

```
    public getStates(countryId: number) {
          let url = this.configManagerService.statesApiUrl;
          const httpHeaders = this.getHeaders();
          return this.httpClient.get(`${url}/${countryId}`, { headers: httpHeaders }).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
    }

    public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
          console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError('Value list currently not available.');
    }
```

I am not able to write a unit test case which covers the `handleError` method. Can somebody please educate me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HttpClientTestingModule` and flush an error for the API call.

[This](https://braydoncoyer.dev/blog/how-to-unit-test-an-http-service-in-angular/) is a good source but it seems like he is not testing the error route.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463377/7365461) to see how to mock an error for the Http Call. Once you mock an error, the `handleError` method should be called.