# Unit test observable catchError pipe

Tags: angular, jestjs, rxjs

I have a service that fetches data like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeartbeatHttpService {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient);

  constructor(@Inject('WEBSERVICE_BASE_URL_TOKEN') protected webserviceUrl: string) { }

  getHeartbeat() {
    return this.fetchHeartbeat();
  }

  private fetchHeartbeat() {
    return this.http
      .get(this.webserviceUrl.concat('/heartbeat'))
      .pipe(catchError((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to fetch heartbeat data.');
        throw err;
      }));
  }
}
```

I already have a unit test for fetching the data, and I want another unit test for testing a failure and going into the `catchError` pipe, however, I cannot trigger it correctly using Jest.

Currently, my test is like so:

```
  it('should handle error', () => {
    const mockError = { message: 'oops! test error' } as Error;

    // I have tried mockImplementation and mockReturnValue with throwError operator and neither has triggered the catchError in my method.

    jest.spyOn(HttpClient.prototype, 'get').mockImplementation((args) => {
      return throwError(() => mockError);
    });

    // jest.spyOn(HttpClient.prototype, 'get').mockReturnValue(throwError(() => mockError));

    service.getHeartbeat().subscribe({
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Can anyone help with correctly mocking a thrown error to trigger the `catchError` pipe?

Comment: Please give a [mre], but see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/http-test-requests#test-for-errors.

Comment: Is this the angular http client?  There's a whole test module for that and even a prior question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028804/how-to-mock-angular-4-3-httpclient-an-error-response-in-testing